# Replacing values with the next unique one

Tags: python, pandas

In my pandas dataframe I have a column of non-unique values
I want to add a second column that contains the next unique value
i.e,

```
col
1
5
5
2
2
4
```

---

```
col addedCol
1     5
5     2
5     2
2     4
2     4
4     (last value doesn't matter)
```

how can i achieve this using pandas?

- I'll clarify what I meant, I want each row to contain the next value that is different than of that row's
  I hope I better explained myself now

Comment: I don't understand; how is `5` the next unique value from `1` in `[1 5 5 2]`? Can you break it down step by step? Maybe you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52522386/edit) your question

Comment: Why row 0 is fill with 5 ? since 5 is not unique

Comment: sure, in the first row, where 1 appears, the next unique value is 5, in the second row, the next unique (different) value is 2, in the third 2 is still the next unique value

Comment: So, @freakazoid usually patience and explaining goes a long way.  I had assumed you had a typo.  But now I realize you wanted a result without explaining how to get it nor showing what you've tried.  Please note, we are not paid to answer your questions.  We are programming enthusiasts who enjoy helping others.  When you take our answering for granted, that becomes offensive and people are less inclined to help.

Comment: @piRSquared I realized due to the responses I must've not explained myself properly, so I edited my question, I hope it's better phrased now

Comment: Must the values be unique **across the series**, or only in the current group of rows. Put differently, what should happen if the series goes `1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1`?

Comment: Note that my edge-case example also repeats that last value. Presumably it doesn't matter what the value is going to be for both the last `1` entries?

Comment: @MartijnPieters assuming your edge case: what is the next unique value?  Relative to the initial cluster?  Relative to the new cluster?  Consider `[1, 2, 3, 1, 4]`: For the second instance of `1`, should the next unique be `2` or `4`.  Strictly speaking it depends on which sequence we want the "Next" to be considering.  If "Next(among sequence of unique values)" then `2` or "Next(among this sequence of non-unique things)" then maybe `4`.  I'd argue, that if you consider multiple clusters, this problem is underspecified.

Comment: @piRSquared: the current selected solution will instead assign `3` to be next to `3`, because the second `1` has been dropped, and so the `3` value put next to `2` is forward-filled instead. I was pointing out that the problem is really underspecified here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you need the next value which is different from the current value.

```
df.loc[:, 'col2'] = df.drop_duplicates().shift(-1).col
df['col2'].ffill(inplace=True)

    col col2
0   1   5.0
1   5   2.0
2   5   2.0
3   2   2.0
```

(Notice that last 2.0 value doesn't matter). As suggest by @MartijnPieters,

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(int)
```

Can make values back to original integers if needed.

---

Adding another good solution from @piRSquared

```
df.assign(addedcol=df.index.to_series().shift(-1).map(df.col.drop_duplicates()).bfill())

    col addedcol
0   1   5.0
1   5   2.0
2   5   2.0
3   2   NaN
```

---

Another example, if `df` is

```
    col
0   1
1   5
2   5
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   10
7   9
```

Then

```
df.loc[:, 'col2'] = df.drop_duplicates().shift(-1).col
df = df.ffill()
```

yields

```
    col col2
0   1   5.0
1   5   2.0
2   5   2.0
3   2   3.0
4   3   10.0
5   3   10.0
6   10  9.0
7   9   9.0
```

Comment: You seem to have dropped row 3 from your first example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters copy/paste error, didn't drop the row :p

Comment: (and once the NAs are gone, after forward-filling, perhaps `col2` can be converted back to the same int dtype).

Comment: Yeah, I checked if your code would drop the row (which would have been surprising)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for input, have added your suggestion ;} cheers.

Comment: Also do not fill the whole df . :-)

Comment: @piRSquared Actually the idea I has is to shift after, just to get the indexes changed, and match them afterwards . Wen thanks man :) good detail

Comment: This will fail if there are multiple clusters of a value. Say `pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5]})`.

Comment: Good point, waiting on OP's response to what happens in this case

Comment: @MartijnPieters see my updated answer.  Does that satisfy what you were thinking as well?

Answer (score 2):

Using  `factorize`

```
s=pd.factorize(df.col)[0]
pd.Series(s+1).map(dict(zip(s,df.col)))
Out[242]: 
0    5.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64

#df['newadd']=pd.Series(s+1).map(dict(zip(s,df.col))).values
```

Under Mart 's condition

```
s=df.col.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
(s+1).map(dict(zip(s,df.col)))
Out[260]: 
0    5.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: notice that in the 2nd row i want 2 to appear, and not 5 (2 is the next unique value)

Comment: This will fail if there are multiple clusters of a value. Say `pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5]})`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that condition , in that case , the accepted answer will not work as well

Comment: Since the `4` in that series is the highest value in the `labels` array, you end up with a `NaN` in the middle.

Comment: The `diff().ne(0).cumsum()` approach is much better!

Comment: My approach is similar @Wen

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

Added additional data with multiple clusters

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [*map(int, '1552554442')]})
```

---

### Two interpretations

We have to consider when there exist non-contiguous clusters

```
df

   col   
0    1   # First instance of `1` Next unique is `5`
1    5   # First instance of `5` Next unique is `2`
2    5   #                       Next unique is `2`
3    2   # First instance of `2` Next unique is `4` because `5` is not new
4    5   #                       Next unique is `4`
5    5   #                       Next unique is `4`
6    4   # First instance of `4` Next unique is null
7    4   # First instance of `4` Next unique is null
8    4   # First instance of `4` Next unique is null
9    2   # Second time seen `2` Should Next unique be null or what it was before `4`
```

#### Allowed to look back

Use `factorize` and add `1`.  This is very much in the spirit of @Wen's answer

```
i, u = df.col.factorize()
u_ = np.append(u, -1)  # Append an integer value to represent null

df.assign(addedcol=u_[i + 1])

   col  addedcol
0    1         5
1    5         2
2    5         2
3    2         4
4    5         2
5    5         2
6    4        -1
7    4        -1
8    4        -1
9    2         4
```

---

#### Only Forward

Similar to before except we'll track the cumulative maximum factorized value

```
i, u = df.col.factorize()
u_ = np.append(u, -1)  # Append an integer value to represent null

x = np.maximum.accumulate(i)

df.assign(addedcol=u_[x + 1])

   col  addedcol
0    1         5
1    5         2
2    5         2
3    2         4
4    5         4
5    5         4
6    4        -1
7    4        -1
8    4        -1
9    2        -1
```

You'll notice that the difference is in the last value.  When we can only look forward, we see that there is no next unique value.